# Is there a way to automatically extend the default home folder on GCP VMs using the 64TB volume limit?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-compute-engine

Like on a Macbook or anything you'd get yourself, etc.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?  https://medium.com/google-cloud/resize-your-persist-disk-on-google-cloud-on-the-fly-b3491277b718

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was [suggested](https://medium.com/google-cloud/resize-your-persist-disk-on-google-cloud-on-the-fly-b3491277b718) by *@Kolban*, **you can resize your your persist disk on the fly**, but you need to participate in this process by following some steps.

On the other hand, **you can use [Cloud Storage FUSE](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse) and have far more than 64Tb storage** [limited](https://cloud.google.com/storage/quotas#objects) only by 5Tb per object and **mounted like a file system**:

> Cloud Storage FUSE is an open source FUSE adapter that allows you to
>   mount Cloud Storage buckets as file systems on Linux or macOS systems.
>   It also provides a way for applications to upload and download Cloud
>   Storage objects using standard file system semantics.

with all the benefits of [Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage):

> Cloud Storage provides worldwide, highly durable object storage that
>   scales to exabytes of data.

So, you can use as more as you need without worrying about current limits and extending.

Keep in mind some **[differences from a POSIX file system](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse#notes)**:

> **Pricing**: Cloud Storage FUSE access is ultimately Cloud Storage access. All data transfer and operations performed by Cloud Storage
>   FUSE map to Cloud Storage transfers and operations, and are charged
>   accordingly. See the pricing section below for details before using
>   Cloud Storage FUSE.
>
> **Performance**: Cloud Storage FUSE has much higher latency than a local file system. As such, throughput may be reduced when reading or
>   writing one small file at a time. Using larger files and/or
>   transferring multiple files at a time will help to increase
>   throughput.
>
> **Availability**: Transient errors do at times occur in distributed systems like Cloud Storage, leading to less than 100% availability. It
>   is recommended that retries be attempted using the guidelines of
>   truncated exponential backoff.
>
> **Directories**: By default, only directories that are explicitly defined (that is, they are their own object in Cloud Storage) will
>   appear in the file system. Implicit directories (that is, ones that
>   are only parts of the pathname of other files or directories) will not
>   appear by default.

more details you can find in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse).

Comment: This worked! Thanks so much! I wish my account was eligible to upvote. :(